# install angular packages - ngx-pagination and charts

Tags: angular, npm-install, package.json

I am a newbie to angular.
In my angular application, I have installed pagination by command `npm install ngx-pagination`
Now I want to install chart, so i have done it using below commands -

```
npm install ng2-charts@2.4.2 --save
npm install chart.js --save
```

But after installing this I am getting error as - 'Can not find module ngx-pagination'

How to solve this issue ? I want both

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of your page where the error is occurred?

Answer (score 0):

mention your need packages in package.json like
**"ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0"** and same for chart.js and ng2-charts.
remove node_modules and do npm install